# pass value from one class/function to another class/function

Tags: python, django

I have written two class one for posting datas for payment and other one to show payment-successful message with `order_id`. I am sending order id from first function and i want to catch this id to show in my payment-successful template.

```
class ApiVIew(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'payment.html'
    def post(self,request):
        r = requests.post(url='www.randomsite.com',params = {'authToken':'12345','card_no':'1234','card_cvv':'****'})
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'response':r.json(),'status':'ok'}))
```

I call this class is ajax and parse there,so if r gives no error then i redirect(`window.location=localhost:8000/success`) to the `success-payment.html` page. so response gives me a json data:

> {'isSuccess': 1, 'order_id': 1cq2,}

so i want to get this `order_id` and pass it to another function/class written below.

```
def payment_successfullView(request):
    return render(request,'payment-successfull.html')
```

How can i achieve so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your json data in session, then from `ApiView` instead of returning `HttpResponse` perform a redirect to url for `payment_successfullView` where you can get the order_id from session and render it in your template.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal than how to delete that data,because after another succesfull payment its going to save another order_id there, and it would be list of order_ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Most simple way**

urls.py:

```
...
path('<str:order_id>/success/', views.payment_successfullView, name='success'),
...
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse
class ApiVIew(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'payment.html'
    def post(self, request):
        r = requests.post(url='www.randomsite.com',params = {'authToken':'12345','card_no':'1234','card_cvv':'****'})
        if r.isSuccess:
            return redirect(reverse('success', args=(r.order_id, )))
        # do your stuff in case of failure here

def payment_successfullView(request, order_id):
    return render(request,'payment-successfull.html', {
        'order_id': order_id,
    })
```

**2. Another method using sessions:**

urls.py:

```
...
path('success/', views.payment_successfullView, name='success'),
...
```

Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect, reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

class ApiVIew(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'payment.html'
    def post(self, request):
        r = requests.post(url='www.randomsite.com',params = {'authToken':'12345','card_no':'1234','card_cvv':'****'})
        if r.isSuccess:
            request.session['order_id'] = r.order_id  # Put order id in session
            return redirect(reverse('success', args=(r.order_id, )))
        # do your stuff in case of failure here

def payment_successfullView(request):
    if 'order_id' in request.session:
        order_id = request.session['order_id']  # Get order_id from session
        del request.session['order_id']  # Delete order_id from session if you no longer need it
        return render(request,'payment-successfull.html', {
            'order_id': order_id,
        })

    # order_id doesn't exists in session for some reason, eg. someone tried to open this link directly, handle that here.
    return HttpResponseForbidden()
```

Comment: hi thanks for the pint point answer.. btw can i do such with out giving order_id in url?

Comment: yes for that you need to use sessions. Save order_id in session in `ApiView` then retrieve that order_id in `payment_successfullView` from sessions. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/sessions/ I personally haven't used sessions much so if I provide you code without running it myself, it might not work, therefore I suggest you try to figure it out yourself.

Comment: i added method using sessions too anyway. It should work, try it out and let me know if it creates any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think the best answer points you in the right direction and let you figure out the fun part.

Tips:

1. Your `APIView` has to [redirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) to `payment_successfullView`
2. You have the `order_id` so you could use a [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview)
3. If you want to display a list of orders (order_id's) use [ListView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

I think using those tips, you'll be fine. Happy coding.

> **Note**
>
> You might want to read about [Form views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#formview) also, such view has an attribute called `success_url`. Ring a bell?